# How to get Bootstrap multiselect dropdown list value as comma seperated string when a POST method is invoked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am Using Bootstrap multiselect dropdown in a Razor view. i need all the selected values as comma separated when SUBMIT the form. But unfortunately i am getting the first (only one) value to the controller action after POSTing.
 Here is my Razor code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Developer, new SelectList(users, "EmployeeID", "DomainID"), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

And here is my JS code

```
$('#Developer').multiselect({
    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: '300',
    buttonWidth: '350',
    onChange: function (element, checked) {
        var brands = $('#Developer option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(brands).each(function (index, brand) {
            selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
    },
    onDropdownHidden: function (e) {
        $('#Developer').val(selected);
    }
});
```

Note that, "Developer" is a string type property of my model

Comment: The correct usage for a multiple select is `@Html.ListBoxFor()` (and remove the `new { multiple = "multiple" }`) and your property needs to be `public string[] Developer { get; set; }` in order to correctly bind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is very easy:

```
$('#Developer').val().join(','); 
//This creates a comma separated string with the selected values
```

So in your `form`, you can add a `hidden input`, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenChoices" id="hiddenChoices" value="" />
```

And in your `jquery` code:

```
$('#Developer').multiselect({
 selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
 enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
 enableFiltering: true,
 maxHeight: '300',
 buttonWidth: '350',
 onDropdownHidden: function (e) {
    $('#hiddenChoices').val($('#Developer').val().join(','));
    //Now the value if hiddenChoices it's like "1,2,3"
 }
});
```

To preselect the values, lets supose you have the value `"1,2,3"`

```
$('#Developer').multiselect('select', "1,2,3".split(','));
```

Comment: Dear Hackerman, Thanks for this solution. but i am still getting that ONE value.I jut put $('#Developer').val().join(',');  instead of  $('#Developer').val(selected); and everything is same as previous. Should i add/remove code in JS section? your solution gives me the expected result in browser console  but values getting lost after POST.

Comment: Thats OK, I will use this. But what will happen when i need to edit this entity. How will I preselect those "Developer"s

Comment: Thanks Hackerman. I think you proposed the best approach. Accepted

Comment: This answer helps me a lot, thanks, but I think you should add a validation to check if `$('#Developer').val()` is null before joining

Answer (score 1):

Multile property passes an array
You could make your developer property in your model as

```
public string[] Developer { get; set; }
```

Or you can receive selected values in your action

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string[] Developer) 
{
   // make them comma separated now if you want 
}
```

Comment: Dear janina, Thanks for proposing a new solution.